# UNION ALL with 4 tables

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, union-all

I am really new with MSSQL and Full Stack development I want to perform UNION ALL with 4 different tables
for a loan-savings management system
The following Code is a stored procedure I have for the 4 tables im getting the error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_GetLoanSavingsDetailsByLoanTakerId, Line 13
> Invalid column name 'GetSavings'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure USP_GetLoanSavingsDetailsByLoanTakerId, Line 13
> Invalid column name 'GiveSavings`

And this is my code I want to achieve the Loan Given to a person,Loan Received from a person,
Savings Taken from a person and Savings Given to a person maintaining the transaction on the same day
`MemberId` is the person I am taking the loan and giving the savings to and `UserId` is the person who wants to give the loan to the member and get/give savings to that same person

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetLoanSavingsDetailsByLoanTakerId]
(
    @MemberId bigint,
    @UserId bigint
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    --EXEC USP_GetLoanSavingsDetailsByLoanTakerId 5, 26


SELECT EntryDate, SUM(LoanGiven) AS LoanGiven, SUM(LoanReceived) AS LoanReceived , SUM(GetSavings) AS GetSavings, SUM(GiveSavings) AS GiveSavings
FROM(  
    SELECT EntryDate, TotalAmount as LoanGiven, 0 as LoanReceived
    FROM tblGiveLoan 
    WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT EntryDate, 0 as LoanGiven, Amount as LoanReceived
    FROM tblReceiveLoan
    WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EntryDate, TotalAmount as GetSavings, 0 as GiveSavings
    FROM tblGetSavings 
    WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
    UNION ALL   
    SELECT EntryDate, 0 as GetSavings , TotalAmount as GiveSavings
    FROM tblGiveSavings
    WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
) t
GROUP BY EntryDate
ORDER BY EntryDate ASC  
 END
```

Comment: Error messages claims that you use MS SQL aka SQL Server, not MySQL. The question is re-tagged.

Comment: *im getting the error* In UNION the names of output rowset are taken from 1st subquery, names/aliases of all another subqueries are ignored.

Comment: Please confirm whether its MySQL or SQL Server, and update your question (the first sentence and tags) accordingly.

Comment: it is SQL Server

Comment: @Akina  
I have another question can you help me please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65918586/automated-monthly-data-generation-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetLoanSavingsDetailsByLoanTakerId]
(
    @MemberId bigint,
    @UserId bigint
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    --EXEC USP_GetLoanSavingsDetailsByLoanTakerId 5, 26


SELECT EntryDate, SUM(LoanGiven) AS LoanGiven, SUM(LoanReceived) AS LoanReceived , SUM(GetSavings) AS GetSavings, SUM(GiveSavings) AS GiveSavings
FROM(  
        SELECT EntryDate, TotalAmount as LoanGiven, 0 as LoanReceived, 0 as GetSavings, 0 as GiveSavings
        FROM tblGiveLoan 
        WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
    UNION ALL   
        SELECT EntryDate, 0, Amount, 0, 0
        FROM tblReceiveLoan
        WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
    UNION ALL
        SELECT EntryDate, 0, 0, TotalAmount, 0
        FROM tblGetSavings 
        WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
    UNION ALL   
        SELECT EntryDate, 0, 0, 0, TotalAmount
        FROM tblGiveSavings
        WHERE UserId = @UserId and MemberId = @MemberId
    ) t
GROUP BY EntryDate
ORDER BY EntryDate ASC  
END
```

Comment: thank you 
It worked perfectly fine
Thank you so much